# Related to pass contents + passbook + ios 6

Tags: objective-c, ios6, passbook

if i want to add some URL, with out exposing the full URL text, is there any way to do that? in pass book. please let me know if any one come across it.

Answer (score 0):

In iOS6 no. For iOS7 yes - if you are a member of the iOS developer program then you can download the new package format reference guide for details of how to do this.